# as3 error: access of possibaly undefind property through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this as3 project, and in frame one of the timeline I tried to load a swf movie named "menu" and in this loaded movie I have an instance of a button named "button1", and I want to add a new EventListener to this "button1". my code is here:

```
var theLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var address:URLRequest = new URLRequest("menu.swf");
theLoader.load(address);

theLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , swfDidLoad);

    function swfDidLoad(evt:Event){
        if(theLoader.content){
            addChild(theLoader);                
            var button:SimpleButton = theLoader.content.button1;
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler1);                
        }
    }

    function handler1 (event:MouseEvent):void
    {       
             removeChild(theLoader);
             gotoAndStop(10);
    };
```

but I get this undefind property error. what should I do? Am i doing this right at all?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting that error is because you are trying to access `button1` on `theLoader.content` which is a non-dynamic `DisplayObject` (this means that only explicitly defined properties/methods are valid). You must first cast it to a `MovieClip` (which *is* dynamic).

You should change that line to:

`var button:SimpleButton = MovieClip(theLoader.content).button1;`